# 'await' outside function error given when running program

Tags: python, database

I am trying to create a database with the module databases

This is the code that I have tried

```
from databases import Database
database = Database('sqlite:///example.db')
await database.connect()

query = """CREATE TABLE HighScores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), score INTEGER)"""
await database.execute(query=query)

query = "INSERT INTO HighScores(name, score) VALUES (:name, :score)"
values = [
    {"name": "Daisy", "score": 92},
    {"name": "Neil", "score": 87},
    {"name": "Carol", "score": 43},
]
await database.execute_many(query=query, values=values)

query = "SELECT * FROM HighScores"
rows = await database.fetch_all(query=query)
print('High Scores:', rows)
```

Its returns an error of "SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"

How do I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use await outside an `async` function.

```py
async myFunc():
    await database.connect()
```

however, in order to call the await functions, you need to await them.
You can do this by making use of the `asyncio` package. (So import asyncio ;)

```py
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.run(myFunc()) # this will run a coroutine without awaiting.
```

You can convert this to work for all of the other functions. However, I would suggest putting everything in `myFunc` instead of making a new function for everything.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)

Comment: No problem! Did this fix it?

Comment: is the myFunc a placeholder for a function, because if so I dont have any functions yet

Comment: @CodyBrynlund Yes and no. Think of `myFunc` as `main.py` (in this case only). You will just run it in `asyncio.run` outside of the func. You can always rename `myFunc` to whatever you want.

Comment: When I try it, it says invalid syntax :(

Comment: @CodyBrynlund Can you paste the code you used?

Comment: its to long to paste

Comment: @CodyBrynlund How about posting it into pastebin?

Comment: You can also paste it in a bunch of other pasting sites (whichever is most accessibly for you is fine :)

Comment: tell me if it doesn't

Comment: all though, I probably won't be on again until 3pm MDT

Comment: @CodyBrynlund Let's move to a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231440/codys-question) so we don't flood the comments. I'll chat from there

Comment: I need at least 20 reputation to chat there :(

Comment: @CodyBrynlund Try again